# Opacity Fading from Transparent to Completely Opaque along a WPF Path?

Tags: wpf, path, opacity

My path is programmatically generated.  I want the beginning of the path to be completely transparent, and the end to be completely opaque, and everything in the middle interpolating between the two opacities.  So the path should fade from completely transparent to completely opaque ALONG the path.  How can I achieve this in the most efficient way possible?

So far, I got an okay-ish approximation by setting the opacity mask of the path to:

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

This follows the general trend of the path, since it makes a gradient along the diagonal connecting the start and end points (I think).  So far, it looks okay in my application, but I would really like a better and more exact approach.

Comment: So you don't just want to fade opacity from Left to Right on the Path, you want to fade opacity on the line segments, from first to last, correct?

Comment: @Meleak: Well, none of those actually.  I want to fade opacity from the 'beginning' of the path to the 'ending' of the path.  The path could be left to right, up to down, or any crazy squiggly pattern.  The opacity should fade ALONG the path, not in any particular linear direction.  Sorry for not being clear in my description.  Let me edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments fro Meleak suggest, the gradient brush you have suggested above is probably the best you can get with the framework itself. However, as you are generating the path programmatically, rather than adding all your segments to a single Path, you could create multiple paths where you gradually reduce the opacity.

However, if you do not have many segments, this might produce a 'stepped' change in opacity. Another possibility is to create a single geometry, then 'chunk' it into as many separate paths as you need, using the PathGeometry.GetPointAtFractionLength method to work out the start and end points of each 'chunk'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.getpointatfractionlength.aspx

HTH

Comment: 'Chunking' was something I wanted to avoid, but you made it sound easy, so I'm going to try it.  Thanks!